# How to get a value of element that was added with ajax in a "live" event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the thing -
a click event adds a bunch of elements on the page, and they all have the same id (is there something wrong here?).

I use a live function to assign click event to all of these elements:

`$("#tag").live('click', function() {
      console.log($("#tag").html());
    });`

When I click on any of them, only the value of first element gets logged.

How can I let the click event know on which of this elements I actually click?
Thanks a lot!

Update: using classes and $(this) is the way to go. Problem solved. Thanks griegs and John!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the added elements really do all have the same ID, and not the same class, then this is a problem. You'll need to post the code that's adding the elements if you'd like help with that.

I can see from the code you posted that you're attaching the live method to the .tag class, but inside the function you're referring to an element with ID #tag instead. You might want to read up on the difference between [classes and IDs](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/cssid.php).

Try this, to solve your problem:

```
$(".tag").live('click', function() { 
    console.log($(this).html()); 
});
```

Alternatively, you can do the following to get the clicked-on element:

```
$(".tag").live('click', function(event) { 
    console.log($(event.target).html()); 
});
```

Comment: I thought I'd be better off with classes and started to fix that. And then I had to go, so I just decided to post the question to see what response it would get. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

try using `$(this).val()` or `$(this).html()`

**edit**

If you want to loop through all thr #tag elements then you can still use $(this) to check the clicked tag against the element you are looping through.  If that makes sense.

btw:  why do you have multiple elements with the same ID?  That's kinda bad.  A better way might be to have elements with common class names that you can reference and attach events to.